# Why do we need double colon operator in fornt of File in config.ru in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When rails application is created, there is a line in `config.ru` file:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
```

Could you explain, why we need `::File` and not just `File`? Will `require File.expand_path` work?

Comment: I do understand what the `::` operator is. The question is about a particular usage. Do we need it in front of `File` in `config.ru`? How different `::File` is in comparison with `File`?

Answer (score 2):

`::` at the beginning represents the main name space. Suppose the current environment is within module `A`. If you have just `File`, then it will first look for `A::File`, and only when such constant does not exist does it look for `File` in the main name space. On the other hand, `::File` refers to `File` in the main name space regardless of whether there is such thing as `A::File`.